# Desired values not displaying after first entry in the table using Javascript and MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to get data from 2 tables in a mysql database. One of which has the id, name, surname, number and gender. The second table has id, product_name and price.

The first table information gets displayed in a html table with a drop down, that has a edit button.

The table gets populated with a while loop.

Once you click edit, a modal open with the name of the person and a drop down with all the products available, once you click on a product then it displays the product price.

My issue is that it only works with the first entry in the database where i can click on the product and it displays the price, anything after the first entry in the table, it does not want to display the price. Here is my code:

**Table**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Phone Number</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>

    <?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM test_table";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>

        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["surname"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["phone_number"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["gender"]; ?></td>
        <td><ul class="t-dropdown-list">
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#SetProductCustomer<?= $row["id"]; ?>"><li class="t-dropdown-item">Edit</li></a>
            </ul></td>
        </tr>

       <div class="modal fade" id="SetProductCustomer<?= $row["id"]; ?>" class="" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <a href="test.php"><span class="close">&times;</span></a>

               <p><?php echo $row['name']; ?> </p>

               <select style="width: 100%;" name="" id="product_info" class="browser-default custom-select-new">

               <?php
               $records = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM products");    
                  while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) {                                             
                  echo '<option value="' . $data['product_name'] . '"
                  data-price="' . $data['price'] . '"  >'
                  . $data['product_name'] . '</option>';
                }

               ?>

             </select>

             <input type="text" name="price" id="price"/>

                </div>
            </div>
          <?php
          }
       }
    ?>
</table>
```

**SCRIPT TO GET THE PRICE**

```
     <script>
     var mySelect = document.getElementById("product_info");

     mySelect.addEventListener("change", function() {
      var myNewOption = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-price");
      document.getElementById('price').value = myNewOption;

      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you inspect the `<option>`s, are all fields filled with the correct values?

Comment: @brombeer, so when i inspect, i can see that the products in the dropdown are all allocated the correct price which gets displayed as data-price. However it does not want to display the price in the input box after the first entry in the table.

Comment: IDs must be unique within an HTML document. For the ID of your modal element itself, you took care of that by appending the row ID - but for your select field and the price field, you neglected to implement something similar.

Comment: @CBroe thank you, i completely missed that. I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so i appended the following  to the ID in the select field and in the price input, which made it work.

```
 <select style="width: 100%;" name="" id="product_info<?= $row["id"]; ?>"" class="browser-default custom-select-new">

 <input type="text" name="price" id="price<?= $row["id"]; ?>"/>
```

and then just adjusted my Javascript to get those values

```
 <script>
 var mySelect = document.getElementById("product_info1");

 mySelect.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var myNewOption = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-price");
  document.getElementById('price1').value = myNewOption;

  });
</script>

 <script>
 var mySelect = document.getElementById("product_info2");

 mySelect.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var myNewOption = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-price");
  document.getElementById('price2').value = myNewOption;

  });
</script>
```